# Ubuntu + ZFS vs Rockstor

Tags: ubuntu, raid, storage, zfs, btrfs

I have a personal fileserver at home with 6 HDs:

- 1 500 GB one for the OS
- 1 4 TB one for temporary data
- four 2 TB ones that we want to configure in some sort of RAID 5 fashion

It looks like I have two options:

- Ubuntu with the four 2 TB drives using ZFS RAID-Z
- Rockstor with the four 2 TB drives using BTRFS

For both of them the OS will be installed on the 500 GB and the 4 TB will be a temporary drive for stuff.

We were leaning towards Ubuntu because then we can still use the machine as a desktop when/if needed (rarely).

Wondering if anyone has any thoughts or recommendations? Having a tough time deciding...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been using ZFS with striped mirrored disks + cache/log devices, on Ubuntu, and now Debian for 6 years or so and it's been pretty good. I've never lost any data and performance is amazing. There are so many features, it's just not the same as Btrfs.

Originally my array was raidz on OpenSolaris, which I moved to Ubuntu with no problems, then upgraded to bigger disks with raid 0+1 and added log/cache SSDs and switched to Debian. Never once had a problem.

I recommend you go with ZFS.

There are also FreeBSD and FreeNAS that both support ZFS out of the box. I have no experience with them.